# How can I fadeOut() each individual li in a ul and keep track of how many li have been clicked on?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a number of tabs created with CSS that contains a ul within a div. I want to use jQuery to fadeOut() each li when clicked on and also keep track of how many lis have been clicked on. This is the code I have so far, it is currently fading out every single li when one is clicked on.

```
        <div class="tab">
            <h2>Lobby</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Sponsor logos are displayed correctly and all link to their relevant sponsor booths</li>
                <li>Top-left (branding) logo is displayed correctly and links to the event homepage</li>
                <li>Lecture Theatre signpost is displayed correctly and links to the Live Redirect</li>
                <li>Exhibition Hall signpost is displayed correctly and links to the event Exhibition Hall</li>
                <li>If Delegate chat is in use, ensure the Minnit chat widget is displayed correctly and working</li>
                <li>Ensure background image is appropriate for the event and displayed correctly, adjustments can be made in the branding tab CSS on the platform</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("li").click(function(){
            $("li").fadeOut()
        });
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you need to reference the element which was clicked on. To do that you can use the `this` keyword within the anonymous function:

```
$("li").click(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut()
});
```

Alternatively you can use an arrow function to make the code more succinct, however you will need to use the `target` property of the event argument in this case:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("li").click(e => $(e.target).fadeOut());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
  <h2>Lobby</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Sponsor logos are displayed correctly and all link to their relevant sponsor booths</li>
    <li>Top-left (branding) logo is displayed correctly and links to the event homepage</li>
    <li>Lecture Theatre signpost is displayed correctly and links to the Live Redirect</li>
    <li>Exhibition Hall signpost is displayed correctly and links to the event Exhibition Hall</li>
    <li>If Delegate chat is in use, ensure the Minnit chat widget is displayed correctly and working</li>
    <li>Ensure background image is appropriate for the event and displayed correctly, adjustments can be made in the branding tab CSS on the platform</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That depends. I would advise against using a global to count the number of clicked elements, and instead retrieve them at the point that data is required, either by an applied class or using `:hidden`